# how we import jTable header names as mysql Table column names in java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to modify MySQL database Table column name according to the jTable header name by java code

Answer (score 1):

To rename column name

alter table tablename change oldname newname newcolumndatatype ;

[check it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

You can write java code  which connect to MySQL database and rename columns by using above suggestion

[Check with java sample code](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/ChangeColumnName.shtml)